# OLS Regression with NeweyWest error term

Tags: linear-regression, correlation

I need to estimate a linear regression with the OLS method. Since I assume the error terms to be correlated, I would like to account for heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation in the error terms. I allready wrote a code, but since I am not good in R at all I wonder whether it is correct.

So far, my code is:

```
library(sandwich)
library(dynlm)
library(lmtest)
myregression <- dynlm(formula = x ~ y + z)
coeftest(myregression, vcov = NeweyWest(myregression))
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Best regards, Jack